# Mysql how to count data from several tables with several conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, union

I have table `mail`:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|    m_id |    dns_id | mail_name    | 
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|        1|         5 | myac1        | 
|        2|         5 | myac2        | 
+---------+-----------+--------------+-
```

`dns_id` it is id from domain name from table `dns`
`m_id`it is key field with id of email
`mail_name` name of email

Table `dns`

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|    dns_id |    acc_id |         dns|
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|         5 |         1 |    test.com| 
|         6 |         1 |   test2.com|            
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

`acc_id` id of my accounts
`dns` name of my domains

How you can see, i have two different domains for one account.
Field `dns_id` from table `dns` linked with `dns_id` from table `mail`. I have mail accounts for `dns_id` with id 5 and with name `test.com`. But i don't have mail accounts for `test2.com` with `dns_id` 6.
I need to calculate count of `dns_id` for `acc_id`
Simple:

```
select count(dns_id) from dns where acc_id = 1;
```

Result:

```
+------------------+
|   count(dns_id)  |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, if i want to make count only for domains, that have mail account in table `mail`. How to do this ? I don't want to calculate domains, where i don't have mail accounts. In this case, i should have:

```
+------------------+
|   count(dns_id)  |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Because my `dns_id` with number 6 with domain `test2.com` does not have mail account in table `mail`.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS`.

Comment: i tried, but i have error:
`ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'domain_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Qualify your columns, e.g. `dns.domain_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(dns_id)
FROM dns
WHERE acc_id IN (
    SELECT m_id FROM mail
)
```

Comment: The `SELECT DISTINCT` is entirely unnecessary under all circumstances, and bad advice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thx for advice. I am new to sql. Whats the alternative

Comment: Just use `SELECT`.  The `IN` operator cannot create duplicate rows so there is no need for `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Also, if you were doing this using the `join` approach, you would probably want to use a `group by` to ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure if I understood it correctly, 
but can you try below query.
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.DNS 
    WHERE (acc_id=1 )
    AND dns_id IN (SELECT d_id FROM dbo.Mail)

Comment: I am getting result as 1